# How do you join two PDO objects in the same foreach loop?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Forgive me because I'm new to PDO. I'm not sure if there is a simple solution. I've been searching online for some time and have yet to find an answer.

I have two different databases that I'm connecting to.

```
try {
    $db1= new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$server;Database = $dbname", $uid, $pwd); 
    $db2= new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$server;Database = $db2name", $db2uid, $pwd); 
}
```

I'm trying to join information from a table on each database based on a common ID. I need to loop through the information to print a list.

```
$sql= 
    "SELECT tableA.name, tableB.messages 
     FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id";

foreach ($db1->query($sql) as $row) {
//HOW CAN I QUERY DB2??
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $msg= $row['messages'];

    echo $name . "etc...";
}
```

How can I modify this code to query both PDOs so that it can print out results in the same foreach loop?

EDIT: I am trying to match up an ID in tableA with an ID in tableB and then print the name field in tableA next to the msg field in tableB when the IDs match.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine (since you don't provide us your DB schema) that you have db1 with table

```
Db1table
    id_1
    name_1
    message_1
```

and db2 with table

```
Db2table
   id_2
   name_2
   message_2
```

And each id_1 refers to common corresponding id_2, eg
`array('id_1'=>1, 'name_1'=>'smth', 'message_1'=>'smth')` must be joined with `array('id_2'=>1, 'name_2'=>'smth', 'message_2'=>'smth')` (as you see, id_1==id_2).

So, code you need is:

```
# make a "indexed" hash by common id column for fast access
$hash_by_id=array();
foreach($db2->query($sql2) as $row2){
    $hash_by_id[$row2['id_2']]=$row2;
}

foreach($db1->query($sql1) as $row1){
    $joined_row2=$hash_by_id[$row1['id_1']]; #pseudo-join
    echo $joined_row2['id_2']==$row1['id_1'] # true
    # from db1
    echo $joined_row2['id_2'];
    echo $joined_row2['name_2'];
    echo $joined_row2['message_2'];
    # from db2
    echo $row1['id_1'];
    echo $row1['name_1'];
    echo $row1['message_1'];
}
```

Comment: This looks like it is working but I am getting an "Notice: Undefined index:" for each id. It looks like joined_row is not getting any data.

Could you show me how to echo out name and message, please?

Answer (score 0):

Don't query inside the `foreach` condition.  Query first, and join the results:

```
// Assuming your two queries are $sql1 and $sql2
// Unless both connections use the same SQL statement...
$res1 = $db1->query($sql1);
$res2 = $db2->query($sql2);

$results = array_merge($res1, $res2);
foreach ($results as $row) {
  // echo the results
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how would you merge the results so that the corresponding id and name displays next to the message?

Comment: @user1 Do you mean you have table relationships that cross two databases?

Comment: @user1 If so, you are better off to query them at the same time.  I think this should work no matter which database is selected in the PDO connection: `SELECT db1.dbo.table.column1, db2.dbo.table.column2 FROM db1.dbo.table JOIN db2.dbo.table ON ....`

Comment: I tried implementing this but I am getting errors. Do you call the select into an sql? IE: $sql = "SELECT db1.dbo.table.column1, db2.dbo.table.column2 FROM db1.dbo.table JOIN db2.dbo.table";

And if so which object would you query. 

To clarify my post: I am trying to match up an ID in tableA with an ID in tableB and then print the name field in tableA next to the msg field in tableB when the IDs match. 

I really appreciate your help.