# PDO / SQLite: Single query covering two related databases

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

### Context

Playing with two of Feeddemon's SQLite databases, *tags.fdb* and *feeds.fdb*, I created this working raw query (tested using Firefox' handy addon SQLite Manager):

```
SELECT tbl_tags.tag_name, feeds.tbl_posts.link
FROM tbl_tags
INNER JOIN feeds.tbl_posts
ON tbl_tags.fd_postid=feeds.tbl_posts.fd_postid
ORDER BY tbl_tags.tag_name
```

It queries both Feeddemon's *tags.fdb* primarily and attached *feeds.fdb* database files (using SQLite's feature `ATTACH feeds.fdb AS feeds`). It lists all tagged posts with their tag names and hyperlinks. As you can see, the database content is related by fd_postid.

An example to visualize what happens:

*tags.fdb*'s tbl_tags table content:

```
fd_postid tag_name
1         rainbow
2         orange
5         green
```

*feeds.fdb*'s tbl_posts table content:

```
fd_postid link
1         google.com
2         stackoverflow.com
3         microsoft.com
4         slashdot.org
5         techcrunch.com
```

Query results, ordered by tag_name:

```
green    techcrunch.com    
orange   stackoverflow.com
rainbow  google.com
```

### Question

How do I implement this single inner join query to cover multiple related databases, using PDO in PHP?

Connecting to two databases in PDO also creates two objects:

```
$db1 = new PDO('sqlite:tags.fdb');
$db2 = new PDO('sqlite:feeds.fdb');
```

But if I want to query, I have to specify a single object:

```
$result = $db1->query('SELECT * FROM sometable');
```

So how do I bridge the gap and use one query to target both databases?

Or can I use SQLite's `ATTACH database AS alias` feature directly in PDO? If so, how? But this would probably be considered bad practice, right? Since PDO is intended to be database non-specific.

I think this user was looking for the same thing, in the end, but never really got to the point of a working code sample:

[How do you join two PDO objects in the same foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984468/)

**Note:** When answering please consider the fact that I'm a front-end/graphics guy, who just started learning PHP/PDO/SQLite since about two months ago. The question is probably above my experience level. I'm surprised I managed to get the raw query working. But I'm learning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access multiple databases from one query in SQLite, you have to `ATTACH` them.

With PDO, it works in same way as you would execute any other SQL command; you just specify a different file name (and directory, if needed):

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:tags.db');
$db->exec('ATTACH \'feeds.db\' as feeds');
$result = $db->query('SELECT tbl_tags.tag_name, feeds.tbl_posts.link ...');
```

While PDO is intended to be mostly independent of the actual database, you cannot avoid specifying the `sqlite:` when opening the database, and the actual SQL dialect you can use always depends on the database. For practical purposes, the `ATTACH` command is logically part of opening the database, and `feeds.tbl_posts` is just a table name.

Note: SQLite searches for table names in all attached databases, so you can omit the database name for unique table names.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! I already tried this before, but didn't escape the ' in the ATTACH command. After fixing that I discovered something weird (to me): it seems to be looking for feeds.fdb in the root installation directory of my webserver, instead of the same directory where I executed the php script (like it does with tags.fdb). Just to test your solution I worked around it by temporarily moving the feeds.fdb into the install directory...but that seems like a really bad solution. I'll keep looking why it does that. But thank you so much for solving my question!

Comment: This method give me error `Could not find driver ... PDO->__construct('sqlite:...`