# How to show the WAL status in PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, wal

My PHP code:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$dbname");
$db->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;");
```

How do I show the status of WAL e.g. "echo....."?

Thx in advance for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can [*query*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) the value:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode;
```

E.g., result: "delete".

> PRAGMA schema.journal_mode;
> [...]
> The first form of this pragma queries the current journaling mode for database. When database is omitted, the "main" database is queried.  *([ref](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode))*

### SQLite PRAGMA journal_mode Example

```sql
PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;
PRAGMA journal_mode;
```

| journal_mode |
| --- |
| wal |
| wal |

*(two times the same result.)*

#### PHP PDO Example

See the following PHP code example how this applies to PDO with the SQLite3 driver:

```php
$dbname = ':memory';
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$dbname");
$db->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;");

$wal_status = ( 
    $db
    ->query('PRAGMA journal_mode;')
    ->fetch()['journal_mode']
);

echo $wal_status, "\n"; # "wal\n"
```

Alternatively, you can use query() to change the journaling mode and obtain the new journal mode directly:

```php
$dbname = ':memory';
$db = new PDO("sqlite:$dbname");
$journalMode = (
    $db
    ->query("PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL;")
    ->fetch()['journal_mode']
);

echo $journalMode, "\n"; # wal
```

Compare with the *second form* documentation:

> The second form changes the journaling mode for "database" or for all attached databases if "database" is omitted. The new journal mode is returned. If the journal mode could not be changed, the original journal mode is returned. *([ref](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode))*

As both examples do not specify the "database" by its name, this is for the single attached database in the $db PDO object, `:memory` specifically in the examples (you likely have a file-name in there).

If you're interested in the topic about attaching multiple databases,
see the [answer to *"PDO / SQLite: Single query covering two related databases"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12887020/367456).

Comment: Thank you for your information.
I changed it to PHP, but I cannot show the PHP code here (problems to format the code in a stackoverflow comment).

Comment: @josefus: No problem, and yes, this is just the SQL query, it should work like any other query, you only need to obtain the result after exec. Or was that you have a follow up question about that? (code in comments work in backticks (\`code\` = `code`.)

Comment: I did this: 
`$wal_status = $db->exec("PRAGMA journal_mode;");
echo $wal_status;`
Thk you @hakre

Comment: @josefus: close, but not exec() but query() (Cf. as well https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), find an update to the answer showing a more verbose and complete PHP PDO example and sorry, I only quickly saw you did comment and I was under the impression it worked for you but seeing now, you were using exec().

Comment: @josefus: Just FYI, I extended the answer a bit more as the new journal mode can be returned when setting it so it shows boths ways now.

Comment: @josefus: ping ;) anything not working of this? did I again missed something? feedback welcome.